# dplyr: group over several variables in a function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to have two lists of grouping variables. let's say `list1 = c("var2","var3","var4")` and   `list2 = c("var2","var3")`

```
dta = data.frame(var1 = c(1:8),
                 var2 = c(rep("AA",4),rep("BB",4)),
                 var3 = rep(c("C","D"),4),
                 var4 = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1))

dta %>% group_by(var2,var3,var4) %>% summarise(mv1 = mean(var1)) %>% 
  group_by(var2,var3) %>% summarise(mv1_2 = mean(mv1))
```

How can I create a function like this

```
sample_fun = function(dta, list1, list2){

    dta %>% group_by(list1) %>% summarise(mv1 = mean(var1)) %>% 
  group_by(list2) %>% summarise(mv1_2 = mean(mv1))

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways to do this -

1. Pure `dplyr` solution using `across` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

sample_fun = function(dta, list1, list2){
  dta %>% 
    group_by(across(all_of(list1))) %>% 
    summarise(mv1 = mean(var1)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(list2))) %>% 
    summarise(mv1_2 = mean(mv1))
}

sample_fun(dta, list1, list2)
# var2  var3  mv1_2
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 AA    C         2
#2 AA    D         3
#3 BB    C         6
#4 BB    D         7
```

2. Using non-standard evaluation with `syms` :

```
sample_fun = function(dta, list1, list2){
  dta %>% 
    group_by(!!!syms(list1)) %>% 
    summarise(mv1 = mean(var1)) %>% 
    ungroup %>%
    group_by(!!!syms(all_of(list2))) %>% 
    summarise(mv1_2 = mean(mv1))
}

sample_fun(dta, list1, list2)

#  var2  var3  mv1_2
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 AA    C         2
#2 AA    D         3
#3 BB    C         6
#4 BB    D         7
```